# Multiple else if Statements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
        $('#bar3').live('click', function() {
            if($('#bar3').attr('class') == '0') {
                console.log("closed")
            } else if($('#bar1' && '#bar2').attr('class') == '0') {
                console.log("Both")
            } else if($('#bar1').attr('class') == '0') {
                console.log("Summary Open")
            } else if($('#bar2').attr('class') == '0') {
                console.log("HIP Open")
            } else {
                console.log("open") 
            }
         });
```

Why does this not work?

I know what it's doing, I just don't know what to change to fix it.

This part is wrong:

```
else if($('#bar1' && '#bar2').attr('class') == '0')
```

Comment: please show the code of html #bar when it's opened and closed

Comment: Can someone verify if we can use numbers for classes with jQuery?

Comment: Problem is not jQuery but HTML/CSS and everything. In any case, even if it works, I do not recommend naming a class "0". At worst, rename it in something like `my-class-0`.

Comment: plus, yeah, if you want to check whether the object has a given class, you should use the `.hasClass()` method, that works even in the case of multiple classes.

Comment: No, I know all about "hasClass"...it's just I thought I should use this method since a script I am using is adding the class "0" and not sure how hasClass would handle a class with a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#bar1' && '#bar2').attr('class') == '0'
```

should be

```
$('#bar1').attr('class') == "0" &&  $('#bar2').attr('class') == "0"
```

&& is a valid java script operator, but not valid as part of a jquery selector.

Comment: One problem, I am using a script that clears the class when the bar is closed and adds the class '0' when it's open....Anything you add will be deleted and replaced with "0"

Comment: Very much appreciated! Thanks for your expert help! I am just a n00b trying to teach myself how to code. I am still pretty rough around the edges, haha. I appreciate the patience!

Comment: BONUS POINTS!! How do I do more than two??? If I want to check and see if bar1, bar2, and bar3 all have the class of 0 ?? I don't keep using strings seperated with && do I? Because it's not working, haha

Comment: Apparently, order matters. I did this:
 else if(($('#bar1').attr('class') == '0') && ($('#bar2').attr('class') == '0') && ($('#bar3').attr('class') == '0')) {
     alert("All three")
    } else if(($('#bar1').attr('class') == '0') && ($('#bar2').attr('class') == '0')) {
     alert("First two")
    } 

And it worked

Comment: Order does matter, the chain of if/else stops at the first satisfied branch.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are simply using the wrong syntax. This:

```
$('#bar1' && '#bar2').attr('class') == '0'
```

would need to be written more like

```
$('#bar1').attr('class') == '0' && $('#bar2').attr('class') == '0'
```

But that still leaves major issues:

- What is `.attr('class') == '0'` supposed to do? Do you have a class named `0`? If so, the correct way would be `.hasClass('0')`.
- You keep re-wrapping DOM elements in jQuery objects. Do it only once and store the results, e.g. `var $bar1 = $('#bar1')` and then use `$bar1` again and again.

Comment: and i believe we cannot use number-only as a class name..so hasClass('0') is pointless as well

Comment: @bondythegreat: I believe the standard forbids it, but I wouldn't be surprised if browsers actually supported it.

Comment: Thanks for the DOM element tip! Bear with me, I am kind of a n00b  :-|

Answer (score 1):

> They aren't actually hardcoded. I grabbed that code from the the
>   property inspector and not my HTML file, sorry bout that! The class is
>   dynamically added by TinyAccordion script – Alex Dec 15 '11 at 2:19

You only need to change in TinyAccordion this code:

```
var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");
parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0,0);
```

to this:

```
var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");
parentAccordion.init("acc","h3",0,0,"your_class_name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on adding the class!

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking two conditions, you're using && with two strings, and passing the result of that to jQuery. You want to do this:

```
else if($('#bar1').attr('class') == '0' && $('#bar2').attr('class') == '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
} else if($('#bar1' && '#bar2').attr('class') == '0') {
```

with:

```
} else if ( ($('#bar1').attr('class') == '0') && ($('#bar2').attr('class') == '0')) {
```

### UPDATE:

I just tried this code, that is working on jsfiddle:

```
$('#bar3').live('click', function() {
    if ($('#bar1').hasClass("0") && $('#bar2').hasClass("0")) {
        alert("Both bars are Open");
    } else if ($('#bar1').hasClass("0")) {
        alert("Bar 1 is Open");
    } else if ($('#bar2').hasClass("0")) {
        alert("Bar 2 is Open");
    } else {
        alert("No bars are open");
    }
});
```

Comment: Just beware that since your HTML contains hard-coded `class="0"`, both bars will look as open until you re-close them; just remove the `class="0"` to solve this problem -- here it is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/XWMF8/

Comment: They aren't actually hardcoded. I grabbed that code from the the property inspector and not my HTML file, sorry bout that! The class is dynamically added by TinyAccordion script